# Json Schema template for valiadtion

Tags: jsonschema

I am new to defining JSON schema and validating json against the schema.

Here is a sample json for which I want to define a json schema template for validation:

```
{
 "version": "1.0",
 "config": {
   "globalConfig": {
      “ClientNames”: [
        “client1”, “client2”, “client3”
       ]
    },
   “ClientConfigs”: [
       {
          “ClientName”: “client1”,
          “property1”: “some value”,
          “property2”: “some value”
       },
       {
          “ClientName”: “client2”,
          “property1”: “some value”,
          “property2”: “some value”
       },
       {
          “ClientName”: “client3”,
          “property1”: “some value”,
          “property2”: “some value”
       }
    ]
}
```

From what I understand “ClientConfigs” would be an array of object (let’s say ClientConfig) which will contain clientName, property1 and property2. Here is what I think schema would like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-01/schema#",
  "title": "ClientConfig",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Some configuration",
  
  "properties": {
    "version": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "config": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/config"
    }
  },
  
  "definitions": {
    "config": {
      "type": "object",
      
      "properties": {
        "globalConfig": {
          "type": "object",
          "description": "Global config for all clients",
          "properties": {
            "ClientNames": {
              "type": "array",
              "minItems": 1,
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "ClientConfigs": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "List of configs for different clients",
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/ClientConfig"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    
    "ClientConfig": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ClientName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property2": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to validate 2 things with jsonschema:

1. ClientName in every element of ClientConfigs array is one of the values from “ClientNames” i.e. individual ClientConfig in “ClientConfigs” array should only contain client names defined in property “ClientNames”.
2. Every clientName present in “ClientNames” should be defined as an element in “ClientConfigs” array. To be more precise, ClientConfig is defined for every clientName present in “ClientNames” property.

Here is an example which is NOT valid according to my requirements:

```
{
 "version": "1.0",
 "config": {
   "globalConfig": {
      “ClientNames”: [
        “client1”, “client2”, “client3”
       ]
    },
   “ClientConfigs”: [
       {
          “ClientName”: “client4”,
          “property1”: “some value”,
          “property2”: “some value”
       }
    ]
}
```

It is invalid because:

1. It doesn’t define ClientConfig for client1, client2 and client3.
2. It defines ClientConfig for client4 which is not present in “ClientNames”.

Is it possible to do such validation using json schema template? If yes, how to validate the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference instance data in your JSON Schema. This is considered business logic and is out side of the scope for JSON Schema.